# How to identify similar images despite some being cropped?

Tags: php, android, image, matlab, image-processing

I have 100 images, all visually similar and I need to search for duplicates. I have an algorithm which can match same colour/pattern/editing etc. but it doesn't support cropping. Meaning if two similar image, one of which is cropped, the result will be different.

I need algorithm which can match two similar images despite of cropping, somehow like tineye works. I got some references but nothing worked.

Here's [an example article for reference](http://hackerlabs.org/blog/2012/07/30/organizing-photos-with-duplicate-and-similarity-checking/).

Comment: What topic do the images have? Are they representing scenery, buildings, people, faces etc? Different approaches apply to different topics.

Comment: Any two images,which can building or whatsoever but mostly human faces.Like profile picture we use in fb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track using hashing for identifying nearly-duplicates. I believe [*locality sensitive hashing*](http://www.intel-research.net/Publications/Pittsburgh/101220041412_279.pdf) can give you the extra mileage you need. It takes into account the locality of the image features from which it computes the hash key and thus achieves better performance for the task of near-duplicates detection.

Comment: Ok,whatever you are saying i will try but can you identify some other method?